# Scheme programming in ANSYS - do loop

Tags: scheme, fluent, ansys

I need to create code that will load some file into the ANSYS Fluent software, then create a surface, and then - calculate medium pressure on that surface.
These three actions have to be repeated 100 times.
I write a do loop, which you can see below, but it doesn't work with these three actions. It works for only one action (any of these 3). Please tell me where my mistake is, and how to change the code. 
Is there even a possibility of making multiple commands in a do loop?

Regards

```
(Do ((x 1 (+ x 1))) ((> x 100))
(Ti-menu-load-string (format #f "file read-case-data K:\USERS\mnowak\artykulzautosavemnaprawa\postprocessing\caseanddatadoanalizy\Fluentmesh14-58-0000~a.cas.gz" x))
(Ti-menu-load-string (format #f "surface plane-surf-aligned ooooo~a outlet2 -0.0291707 -0.0056188 0.13" x))
(Ti-menu-load-string (format #f "report surface-integrals area-weighted-avg ooooo~a () pressure y pressure1" x))
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this question has a lot to do with ANSYS Fluent, and not so much to do with Scheme. It looks like a lot of the ANSYS Fluent questions on Stack Overflow use the [fluent] tag, even though the description of that tag indicates it's not actually the right one...

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but for anybody having the same issue

Try to wrap your commands inside ***(begin ....)***

```
(Do ((x 1 (+ x 1))) ((> x 100))
(begin 
    (Ti-menu-load-string (format #f "file read-case-data K:\USERS\mnowak\artykulzautosavemnaprawa\postprocessing\caseanddatadoanalizy\Fluentmesh14-58-0000~a.cas.gz" x))
    (Ti-menu-load-string (format #f "surface plane-surf-aligned ooooo~a outlet2 -0.0291707 -0.0056188 0.13" x))
    (Ti-menu-load-string (format #f "report surface-integrals area-weighted-avg ooooo~a () pressure y pressure1" x))
))
```

This schould work out